# How to make connection to remote SQL Server from dynamic ports

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

I can connect to a SQL Server with `"Data Source=DDPSERVER\DDPSQL..."` connection string. I try to make remote connection to this server. I checked the server - it does allow remote connections and TCP/IP is enabled. I also know ip and dynamic ports number (58756).

But when I try to connect remotely with

```
"Data Source=ipnumber,58756\DDPSERVER\DDPSQL..."
```

the connection fails.

What should I do to make the connection without changing the existing server network configuration?

Comment: If you are already able to transparently connect via host\instance name, why do you need to connect via IP + port? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to connect the server from a web application.Thus i need to establish remote connection

Comment: If your remote web application server cannot resolve and access via host\instnace name, it won't be able via IP + port as well. Your issue is very likely causes by the firewall configuration of your database server machine where you need to allow dynamics port ranges for access to SQL service.

Comment: Try looking on [dba.se] where you'll very likely find others that already faced the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you ensure that the **SQL Browser Service** is running you don't need to specify the port or IPAddress. You simply need the computername and instance name.

```
Data Source=myServerName\theInstanceName
```

This assumes that the servername is resolving correctly.

A good resource for connection strings is https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: This is key.  You can mess around with settings all you like, and that's what most google searches will land you at.  Simply enabling this service makes it easy.